# MenuItem visibility based on submenu item state

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a MVVM-based WPF context menu and want to bind the visibility of a menu item to the `IsEnabled` property of its submenu items. The problem is: the root `MenuItem` is always visible, even when all children menu items are disabled. But moving the cursor on the menu item makes it hide and I really have no idea why.

[image: Visualization of the problem]

Here is my xaml code:

```xml
<MenuItem x:Name="SelectionMenuItem" Header="{x:Static language:CommonRes.Selection}">
    <MenuItem.Visibility>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AnyBoolToVisibilityConverter}">
            <Binding
                ElementName="SelectGroupMenuItem"
                Mode="OneWay"
                Path="IsEnabled" />
            <Binding
                ElementName="SelectGraphMenuItem"
                Mode="OneWay"
                Path="IsEnabled" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </MenuItem.Visibility>

    <MenuItem
        x:Name="SelectGroupMenuItem"
        Command="{Binding SelectGroupCommand}"
        Header="{x:Static language:CommonRes.Group}"
        Visibility="{Binding IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    <MenuItem
        x:Name="SelectGraphMenuItem"
        Command="{Binding SelectGraphCommand}"
        Header="{x:Static language:CommonRes.ObjectGraph}"
        Visibility="{Binding IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
</MenuItem>
```

and the code of my Converter

```cs
public class AnyBoolToVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="values"></param>
    /// <param name="targetType"></param>
    /// <param name="parameter"></param>
    /// <param name="culture"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(!values.All(val => val is bool))
            return Visibility.Collapsed;

        return values.Any(val => (bool)val) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <param name="targetTypes"></param>
    /// <param name="parameter"></param>
    /// <param name="culture"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException($"ConvertBack not Supported for {nameof(AnyBoolToVisibilityConverter)}");
    }
}
```

I hope some of you can help me to find the problem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you change the `IsEnabled` property of your `MenuItem`?

Comment: Its changed by the command binding when CanExecute returns a value. This happens at the initialisation process.

Comment: okay so in your case, can we statically set IsEnabled to false to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Remove the command binding and statically set the IsEnabled property of all submenu items to false works. Looks like the binding of the submenu items wont be touched until they appear. Any idea why ?

Comment: Probably because CanExecuteChanged is not raised early enough. Try to manually raise the event maybe?

Comment: Yes. But its strange that it is executed on all root elements during the initialisation process, but not on submenu elements. Ill have to figure out why. Thanks so far :)

Comment: Manually raise the CanExecuteChanged event of both commands in the loaded event of the control does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `Items` of a `Popup` wont evaluate their Bindings until the `Popup` calls the `IsSubmenuOpenChanged` callback and calls `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` after the `IsSubmenuOpen` Property is changed ([Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/MenuItem.cs,f6b031dd8baedf62)).

So i ended up with another Command for the root `MenuItem` that verifies the CanExecute of all submenu commands.

Comment: you should mark this as an answer I think:) Nice job investigating it though.